# execute linux shell command from python script

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I have a python script that contains a Linux shell command. I'm using `subprocess.check_output`. My question is about the faster python method to execute a Linux shell command from python script like `os.system()`.

Comment: Sorry, what’s your question? Which one is faster? `os.system` has the overhead of spawning a shell (and is easy to use unsafely besides), so it’s probably slower, but you can benchmark it.

Comment: my question is what is the faster python method to execute a  linux shell command

Comment: It’s `subprocess.check_output`, so just keep using that. And if you find yourself with two options like this… [time them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).

Comment: ok thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

- I like subprocess.Popen, but it has troubles (maybe it can't) to deal with '>' ==> unconvenient if you have a '>' in the command line
- otherwise subprocess.check_output

Answer (score 0):

The better way:

```
from subprocess import call
call('ls')
```

Please check:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html